# Can a electrical heating element heat gas in sealed vessel above the heating element's initial temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have attached drawing to explain my question. What will happen when the air in the vessel reaches the temperature of the heating element? [image]

Comment: This is better considered when thinking about power, if you constantly add power and do not let any power (heat) out the temperature will rise to infinity.  Most likely your resistor will burn out. You can also consider a resistor in a vacuum .... it will get very hot, the temperature is never constant.

Answer (score 1):

> What will happen when the air in the vessel reaches the temperature of
>   the heating element?

I believe the temperature of both the heating element and the air will continue to rise until there is some relief, either in eventual heat transfer to the surroundings, or mechanical failure.

There are two forms of energy transfer between the surroundings (outside the vessel) and the gas (the system): Heat and work. The main types of work transfer possible are boundary work (expansion/contraction of the vessel walls), shaft work (due to a shaft connecting the system to the surroundings producing rotary motion) and electrical work (by way of electrical conductors going through the vessel walls) connecting an external power source to the heating element.

*If* your vessel is perfectly rigid and perfectly insulated, any boundary work (expansion of the vessel walls) or heat transfer, is precluded. There is no shaft connected between your system and surroundings, therefore no shaft work. You only have electrical work crossing the boundary (vessel walls) between the gas and the surroundings.  The power delivered to the system is constant at 100 Joules per sec except there will be some reduction due to increase in resistance with temperature, but I don't believe it will never be reduced to zero.

When the heating element is first turned on, the electrical power increases the temperature of the heating element and it, in turn, transfers heat internally to the gas. As the the gas temperature approaches the temperature of the heating element the heating element temperature will also rise and there will likely be a finite temperature difference between the two as they both rise so that the internal heat transfer continues, albeit at a slower rate.

All the while this is happening the pressure and the temperature of the gas and the heating element in the vessel keeps increasing. The process will have to eventually cause heat transfer across the insulation since no insulation is perfect, and bulging (expansion) of the walls of the vessel since no vessel is perfectly rigid. The ultimate outcome may well be the rupture of the vessel wall or the melting of the heating element causing power to cease.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just one more point of failure to consider.  At some point the resistive element will become too hot to remain connected to itself, at that point the wire would break, the circuit would break, and heating would stop.  Also, I get the feeling you would actually quickly start to lose energy as you're approaching the temperature where this either breaks or explodes, because resistance would really start to become a limiting factor (up until the wire or container breaks).

Comment: @JMac yes I realized that and added it before seeing your comment.

Comment: I want to thank Dave and Bob D for their time and effort. I was hoping for the answers they provided. I'm new to this site and have not found the best way to thank people for helping me. Harold LaFonte, Birmingham, Alabama

Comment: @Harold Wayne LaFonte Since you’re new at the site you may not be aware that there is an “accept” button with each answer that you can click if you find an answer acceptable